# Apache2 : Limit virtual host to one domain name

Tags: django, dns, apache2

I want to do something but I can't find an answer (Maybe I badly searched). I don't know if it is possible so say me if it's not.

I would like to limit an Apache virtual host to one and only domain name : bde.yggdrasil.cafe. So that if the user try to access this website using 90.90.3.57 or another domain name it is listed as not existing website. Here is my extra/bde.conf which is included in httpd.conf, you'll understand the problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      bde.yggdrasil.cafe
    ServerAdmin     my@email.fr
    DocumentRoot    /srv/http/bdeweb

    #Some django config
    #[...]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bde.yggdrasil.cafe
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName      bde.yggdrasil.cafe
    ServerAdmin     my@email.fr
    DocumentRoot    /srv/http/bdeweb

    #Some django config
    #[...]

    SSLEngine on
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bde.yggdrasil.cafe/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bde.yggdrasil.cafe/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

If I use this code and I try to connect to 90.90.3.57 or yggdrasil.cafe using http protocol my request is caught by Django which returns an error 400 (It is good but not what I want to get). if I connect to bde.yggdrasil.cafe using http it redirect me correctly to https.

## DNS Redirection

I think it can be useful so I give you my DNS Redirections:

```
yggdrasil.cafe      --> 90.90.3.57
bde.yggdrasil.cafe  --> yggdrasil.cafe
```

## Removing Django config

If I remove the Django configuration in my HTTP virtual host and I use the following file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      bde.yggdrasil.cafe

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bde.yggdrasil.cafe
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName      bde.yggdrasil.cafe
    ServerAdmin     my@email.fr
    DocumentRoot    /srv/http/bdeweb

    #Some django config
    #[...]

    SSLEngine on
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bde.yggdrasil.cafe/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/bde.yggdrasil.cafe/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to connect to my server using 90.90.3.57 or yggdrasil.cafe I fall on "Indexes of /" (Which is bad, really bad).

I would like Apache to ignore the connection if the user doesn't user the subdomain "bde.yggdrasil.cafe".

## Why I want to do that ?

This domain is for all my stuff, including a future personal showcase website I would like to host on "yggdrasil.cafe" domain name (without subdomain).
So the important is not the result but I would like to know if it is possible to add an other VirtualHost on "yggdrasil.cafe" domain name afterward without Django catching it.

Thanks for your time

Comment: So what **exactly** do you want to happen if user enters `http://90.90.3.57` or `http://yggdrasil.cafe` in his address bar?

Comment: An error like "this site isn't working" or "connection timed out". But the problem is not the result. I'd also like to know it's possible afterward to use the ServerName yggdrasil.cafe or if django will catch it.

Comment: Of course, just add another VirtualHost with `ServerName      yggdrasil.cafe`; for the beginning you can have simple `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

Comment: Well thank it look like it is working. I don't get the 400 error anymore.
What exactly does `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` ?

Comment: it rewrites everything to "Forbidden" http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f

Comment: The main point here is that any request that does not have matching ServerName in any VirtualHost, will be served by the first VirtualHost.

Comment: I have an other quesiton for my internship. I have a wesbite like `xx.xx.xx.xx/foo` i set up an https virtualhost with no server name and all other url like `xx.xx.xx.xx/bar` and `xx.xx.xx.xx/foobar` use https. HOw can i limit this to `xx.xx.xx.xx/foo` ?

Comment: Please post a new question with `apache` tag, it will be easier to follow and you can explain what you want to achieve in more detail. When giving examples (if you don't want to share real domain name) for hostnames use `example.com` or `something.example.com`, for example public IP addresses use `203.0.113.nn`. This way it will be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

As said by Dusan Basic

> Of course, just add another VirtualHost with `ServerName yggdrasil.cafe`; for the beginning you can have simple `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

It fixed the problem :)